# ForeignKey navigation property value not showing up in Details and Delete Views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have two models `Project` and `Category` where each project contains multiple categories.

Project.cs

```
public class Project
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name="Project Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}
```

Category.cs

```
public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name="Category Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("Project")]
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }

    public Project Project { get; set; }
}
```

After scaffolding when I click on `Details` or `Delete` (after adding some projects and categories) link for a category, the project name does not show up in both the views! Only the label shows up. It shows up in `Index` and `Edit` views though. What could be the reason for that?

**Edit**

This is `Details` action

```
    public ActionResult Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Category category = db.Categories.Find(id);
        if (category == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(category);
    }
```

When I added a line `var pro = category.Project` just before returning the `View(category)`  and started debugging, the `pro` variable was set to `null`. In `Index` action the project is explicitly included `db.Categories.Include(c => c.Project).ToList()` but not in `Details`. Do I need to include it explicitly? If yes, how?

Comment: Well neither are virtual for a start. Should be `public virtual ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }` and `public virtual Project Project { get; set; }`

Comment: Yes, this was the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set your navigation to be virtual(lazy loading)

```
public virtual Project Project { get;set; }
```

or you can use eager loading using Include method(No need for virtual keyword)

```
Category category = db.Categories.Include(c => c.Project).FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == id);
```

[MSDN Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx#eager)